# Python iteration differences

Tags: python, iteration

Why in Python does this happen, invoking only the iterable '(i)'

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(a[2], len(a)):
    print(i)
```

will print: `3 4 5`

but invoking the iterable as (`a[i]`)

```
for i in range(a[2], len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

will print: `4 5 6`

I just can't understand this.

Comment: Because `a[2]` is the *third* element of `a` -- start counting at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version you are creating a **range**; you are asking for the integers between `a[2]` (which is `3`) and `len(a)` (which is 6):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[2]
3
>>> len(a)
6
>>> list(range(3, 6))
[3, 4, 5]
```

The only relationship to `a` is that you used values *from* `a` to build the range. The `range()` gives you the integers between those numbers, including the start, so to count from 3 to 6, not including 6, is to produce the numbers 3, 4 and 5.

In your second example, you then used those numbers to index *back into `a`*:

```
>>> a[3]
4
>>> a[4]
5
>>> a[5]
6
```

Note that these indexes reference values from `a`, which happen to be integers too. The value at each index is not the same as the index, the indexes and values *are not the same thing*.

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that Python lists are indexed *starting at 0*, not 1:

```
>>> a[0]
1
```

The value at index 0, the first value in `a`, is `1`.

Comment: Of course, how could I miss it, too many numbers in my head, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The first element in a list starts with 0.

To get the number 1 from the list you would do `a[0]`.

Therefore, the second way is doing `i[3]` which is `4` because the list index starts at 0. This process continues until the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of how indexes are numbered.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Where [1] is at index 0, [2] is at index 1 and so on.

In your first part of code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(a[2], len(a)):
    print(i)
```

You're asking python to print the **numbers** [3-6), which is 3, 4 and 5

In the second part of your code:

```
for i in range(a[2], len(a)):
    print(a[i])
```

You're asking python to print the **values** at **indexes** [3-6), which is 4, 5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(a[2], len(a))` is equivalent to `for i in range(3,6)`, so `i` will take on the values 3, 4 and 5 in succession, as your first result confirms.

For your second result, you would be printing `a[3]`, `a[4]`, and `a[5]`, or 4, 5 and 6 in succession, as (again) your second result confirms.